# Pandas Pivot Table counting based on condition and sum columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have DateFrame as shown below.
I need to add a few columns to dft (pivot output). First one to calculate sum of products sold daily, it's like margine but only for sum column not len. I tried
dft['Fruit Total']=df.iloc[:,0:3].sum(axis=1) but it didn't work.
also I want to add column counting values > than 2 for each row in column sum. like in the picture

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ["22.10.2021", "22.10.2021", "22.10.2021", "23.10.2021", "23.10.2021", "25.10.2021", "22.10.2021", "23.10.2021", "22.10.2021", "25.10.2021"],
    'Product': ["apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "apple","apple", "apple", "orange", "orange", "orange"],
    'sold_kg': [2, 3, 1, 6, 2,2, 3, 1, 6, 2,]})
df['day']=pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.day

dft=df.pivot_table(values='sold_kg', columns ='day', index='Product', aggfunc=[np.sum,len])
dft
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
dft=df.pivot_table(values='sold_kg',columns='day', index='Product', aggfunc=['sum','size'])
```

First flatten `MultiIndex in columns` with mapping:

```
dft.columns = dft.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
```

Then select columns by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) and `sum`, for count values greater or equal use [`DataFrame.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) and count `True`s by `sum`:

```
dft['Fruit Total'] = dft.filter(like='sum').sum(axis=1)

dft['Count >= 2'] = dft.filter(like='size').ge(2).sum(axis=1)
print (dft)
         sum_22  sum_23  sum_25  size_22  size_23  size_25  Fruit Total  \
Product                                                                   
apple         8       2       2        3        1        1           12   
orange        7       7       2        2        2        1           16   

         Count >= 2  
Product              
apple             1  
orange            2
```